# How can I disable the Angular UI Datepicker buttons outside of the current month?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the Bootstrap UI Datepicker in Angular, and it is working OK. However, when i am in month view, the days outside the month have a CSS class on the span called text-muted which I have set to display:none.

This is all well and good - I cannot see the dates in other months now, which matches my design. But the enclosing buttons of these dates are still clickable, and there does not seem to be a class or hook of any kind to disable them. Any one solved this - I thought it would be a simple config on the Datepicker directive itself, but must be overlooking the answer?

So, if I am in May, I have turned off the dates for April and June, so you cannot see the dates, but the buttons are still clickable to go to those dates in the other months....

---

To clarify, if the current date is May, and I am looking at May in the view, I do not want to be able to see or click on dates in April or June. However, when I use the next month button, and am viewing the month of June, I do not want to be able to see dates in May or July.

Comment: To clarify, if the current date is May, and I am looking at May in the view, I do not want to be able to see or click on dates in April or June. However, when I use the next month button, and am viewing the month of June, I do not want to be able to see dates in May or July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a decorator that can access the `activeDate` property of the datepicker controller, which will tell you which month is being viewed. Then override the `isDisabled` function on the controller so that if you are on the day view, and the month is not the active month, the date is disabled.

```
angular.module('app').config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;

        directive.compile = function() {
            return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                link.apply(this, arguments);

                ctrls[0].isDisabled =  function(date) {
                    return (scope.datepickerMode === 'day'
                        && (date.getMonth() !== ctrls[0].activeDate.getMonth()
                            || date.getYear() !== ctrls[0].activeDate.getYear()));
                };
            }
        };
        return $delegate;
    }]);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/ebt17y22/)

Comment: This does not work as required. Your code only works for the CURRENT month. OK, it disables the dates outside of the current month, but I need the current month to be the one you are looking at, not just the month that it actually is. So if it is currently May, I do not want to see or be able to click the dates for April or June. But when I navigate to June using the next button in the month view, I do not want to be able to click on dates in May or July. Make sense?

Comment: Gotcha. In this case you need to be able to access the activeDate property in the datepicker controller, which will require a decorator. Code updated

Comment: Seems like overkill, but you are most definitely The Man. Accepted as the answer - it is now fully working and integrated into my codebase

Comment: I tried to use this in angular 1.5.11 and I am finding that ctrls[0] is undefined and thus I cannot override the isDisabled function. Any suggestions?